# Vue test utils watch tests

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs, vue-cli, vue-test-utils

How can I keep the `npm run test:unit` command running when I'm writing and saving my tests, I need something like `npm run serve` with hot reload, I've tried `npm run test:unit --watch` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suggest to register a new command script for watching tests to use `--watch` option directly of `vue-cli-service`:

`package.json`

```json
{
  "scripts": {
     // ...
    "test:unit:watch": "vue-cli-service test:unit --watch",
  }
}
```

Then you would run:

```sh
npm run test:unit:watch // or yarn test:unit:watch

// You can even run for specific test as well

npm run test:unit:watch -- yourTest.spec.ts
```

Answer (score 2):

The [`npm` docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-run-script#description) state:

> As of [`npm@2.0.0`](https://blog.npmjs.org/post/98131109725/npm-2-0-0), you can use custom arguments when executing scripts. The special option `--` is used by `getopt` to delimit the end of the options. `npm` will pass all the arguments after the `--` directly to your script:
>
> ```
> npm run test -- --grep="pattern"
> ```

So use this on the command line:

```
                  
npm run test:unit -- --watch
```

Alternatively, you could use [`yarn`](https://yarnpkg.com/), which doesn't require the `run` command or the separating `--`:

```
yarn test:unit --watch
```